# how can I make IsDate work correctly? It's currently returning false for values that are dates

Tags: excel, vba

There is a named range of cells that contains text and dates, and I'm trying to find the first column of the first date.

The IsDate function isn't working for cells that are dates even though the first part of the message box correctly formats it as a date (see code below).

I've tried using:

- isDate(rRange(1,j))
- isDate(rRange(1,j).value)
- isDate(rRange(1,j).value2)

but none of them are returning true for cells that are dates

```
 Dim oldDate as Variant
 'EDIT: clarified that rRange is indeed set as a Range
 Dim rRange as Range
 Dim colValueOfnumDaysInOldMonth as Integer
 Dim numDaysinOldMonth as Integer

 '"HolidaySchedule" is a named range on Sheet3 for cells $C$6:$AJ$90
 Set rRange = Sheet3.Range("HolidaySchedule")

 'rRange("s1") contains a valid date
 oldDate=rRange("s1")

 'numDaysInOldMonth correctly gives the # days in the oldDate's month
 numDaysInOldMonth = Day(DateSerial(Year(oldDate), Month(oldDate) + 1, 1) - 1)

    For j = 1 To rRange.Columns.Count
       'Using this MsgBox to test the values
        MsgBox Format(rRange(1, j), "yyyy/mm/dd") & " : " & IsDate(rRange(1, j).Value)
        If IsDate(rRange(1, j).Value) Then
            colValueOfnumDaysInOldMonth = j + numDaysInOldMonth - 1
            'MsgBox "Last day of old month: " & Format(rRange(1, colValueOfnumDaysInOldMonth), "yyyy/mm/dd")
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
```

The first 5 messageboxes show:

Name : False

Position: False

2019/09/01 : False

2019/09/02 : False

2019/09/03 : False

Comment: You could try formatting the date you pass to `IsDate` like you do in the first part.

Comment: I'll consider that as a last resort, but my question is that if the messagebox can know how to take rRng (1,j) and format it into a date, doesn't Excel already know that rRange(1,j) is a date?

Comment: Did you try to define rRange as Range?

Comment: Ah yes sorry i did do that in my original code - I rewrote some code here for clarity's sake and mistyped it. rRange is indeed a Range

Comment: @newtovba It knows to format it as a date because you told it to do so.

Comment: I tried your code and it works... the only issue is, maybe, the oldDate value

Comment: Your debug does not include the *unformatted* value that you are trying to `IsDate`.  For example, `IsDate(43719)` is `False`, but `IsDate("2019/09/11")`, `IsDate("2019-09-11")`, `IsDate("11 9 2019")` and `IsDate("Sep 11 19")` are all `True`.  However, all of those will `Format` to `"2019/09/11"` if you tell them to.

Comment: Hmm. The underlying value is indeed something like 43719 but I've formatted the cells as "Sunday" , "Monday" etc based off the cell value using the number format in 'regular' excel

Comment: @newtovba format your excel range as date format then your `ISDATE` will work

Comment: If your date values are [indeed dates](https://superuser.com/q/299437/52365) and not just text with applied Date formatting, then `IsDate` should certainly work. `IsDate(r)` is the same as `IsDate(r.Value)`. `IsDate(r.Value2)` is always going to be False because the very point of Value2 is to not give out a Date.

Comment: @newtovba If you do `MsgBox rRange(1, j).Value`, do you get 43719 (`IsDate(43719)=False`), "11/09/2019" (`IsDate("11/09/2019")=True`) or "Wednesday" (`IsDate("Wednesday")=False`)

Comment: Chronocidal for Msgbox rRange(1,j).value, I get 43719. No wonder it's throwing "False" - weird that Excel can convert 43719 to a date but if you do IsDate, it only recognizes it as a number

GSerg Got it.

@BrianMStafford Looks like you're right - IsDate(Format(rRange(1, j), "yyyy/mm/dd")) returns true. Will mark as a plus 1